# Windows Store App Ads shows only Microsoft ads

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I have created a windows store app. I included ads from Microsoft pubCenter. It has been published today and I downloaded it on my laptop and a friend's. In both occasions the ads only show Microsoft advertising ads. Nothing more, nothing less. I added a simple adcontrol line in my xaml as advised and in application id I inserted what was given in pubcenter and same in ad-unit. Is there something wrong with Microsoft Ads?

Comment: They use an algorithm to determine what are the best ads to display. This is likely based on your past browsing history. If you want to see if they'll change, maybe try bing-ing a bunch of different topics and see if the ads pick up on that. It also may be that it defaults to Microsoft Ads until it can sync the roaming data and show which ads to display in a targetted manner.

Comment: @NateDiamond so it is probably not my fault?

Comment: I don't believe so, no. At least, it's perfectly feasible that it is not your fault.

Comment: @NateDiamond I have been using bing for some time now though and I think in other apps I downloaded from the store show ads properly

Comment: I think what's most likely is that the apps possibly individually sync up. It may also be that your app doesn't have enough users to create target demographic info yet. Or that your apps target demographic is MSFT customers.

Comment: could you make everything you said an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft Ads use an algorithm designed for targeted advertising based off of information they receive from the users of a given application. Sometimes the advertising targets a specific user, sometimes it targets a specific app's demographic.

There are quite a few possible reasons that your app is displaying primarily Microsoft ads. It could be that you and your friend are both prime targets for Microsoft products. It could be that your app's demographic or genre is targeted for Microsoft ads.

It could also be that Microsoft's own ads are the default (likely, I'd think). It may take a bit for the demographics information to be received by Microsoft ads, or any other numerous reasons that the default ads are currently being displayed.

Basically, as of right now, there is nothing pointing at this being your fault. With more datapoints over more time, we could possibly begin to eliminate unlikely causes (such as sync time on a specific device).

I don't think you have anything to worry about now. If your ad revenue is particularly low or otherwise anomalous, then maybe there is some need for concern, but until there is some more information, we can only speculate.