# Using AdMob with Windows Store apps

Tags: mobile, windows-store-apps

There is a restriction in Google Adsense posted [here](https://support.google.com/adsense/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=68724) that says:

> The use of AdSense for mobile in a mobile application is a violation
>   of AdSense policies. A mobile application constitutes any downloadable
>   application, even if a WebView is used to display the ad. Any AdSense
>   for mobile ad units found in mobile applications will be disabled. If
>   you’re looking for an advertising solution for your mobile
>   application, please sign up for AdMob, Google’s leading mobile
>   advertising display product.

So if I read this correctly Windows Store Apps that run on laptops are considered mobile apps aswell?

But my main question is. Am I allowed by Google to use Admob in Windows Store apps and Where can I find the SDK?

I tried using Microsoft PubCenter. But it shows no advertisements to people that downloaded my app so I am looking for an alternative to monetize my app

Comment: It does sound like you cannot use AdMob for Windows Store Apps. There may be something wrong with your implementation of PubCenter. Are you seeing any statistics in the PubCenter dashboard?

Comment: Before I published my app and was running it on my laptop I was getting ads. Ads that promoted microsoft advertising. Now that my app is published with adcontrol code completely not changed, the ads are not showing......

Comment: Hmmm... That I'm not sure about, but it seems like something you may need to take up with Microsoft, possibly on Connect. It's possible that you haven't set up PubCenter correctly when creating your release for the store. I think that's the first place to check instead of immediately going to another ad provider. There are also other ad providers that Microsoft has promoted, such as AdDuplex and AdRotator. Maybe one of those will work better for you?

Comment: Adduplex does not help with monetization only app promotion. I am looking into adrotator as we speak in order to put apps from different providers simultaneously, but I have issues with pubcenter right now

Comment: I contacted them, they say it should be showing ads. Thanks guys, very informative....

Comment: Have you tried taking a snapshot of the ads not showing up and sending that to them? Also, are you getting ad revenue?

Comment: No ad revenue, and fill rate is 0%. How would I take a snapshot of a an app with no ads and show it as proof of ads not showing?

Comment: You could include your code showing that you're using the ad control properly. Also, you said that there were ads on your desktop during testing. Are there still ads during testing? And they're just not showing up on the production version? Or have they all stopped?

Comment: all of them had stopped

Comment: as for the code, well I have a different question here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21609982/windows-store-app-ads-shows-only-microsoft-ads

which when started out it was only microsoft ads, now shows nothing. This question is for admob